# Create Custom Triangle Matlab

Tags: matlab

Hello i want to make a coustom triangle without using the existing function of matlab, which will start lets say at 300 and will end at 518 , reaching his peak at 408 and max amplitude 1. Note that i want each slope (up-slope and down-slope) should be vectors of 256 elements.So my first thought is to compute a vector va of 256 elements, ok i done it with linspace but then i don't know how to continue. Note that it should be 2 vectors one for up-slope(256 elements) and the other down-slope(256 elements) and it should look like this[image]

any advice appreciated and thanks in advance

Comment: I guess what you really want is `interp1` or `griddedInterpolant` for all your *triangular filter* questions...

Comment: As in: `hat=griddedInterpolant([300,408,518],[0,1,0],'linear','nearest');` and `x=linspace(300,518,100); y=hat(x)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code:**

```
va = linspace(300,408,256);
va1 = linspace(0,1,256);
vb = linspace(408,518,256);
vb1 = linspace(1,0,256);

figure; axis([200 , 600, -0.2, 1.2]);
hold on
plot(horzcat(va,vb),horzcat(va1,vb1),'r-');  %// inclined lines
plot([300,518],[0,0],'r-');                  %// bottom Horizontal line
hold off
```

**output:**

[image]

Comment: @user_dsp No mention. glad it helped :)